# Why doesn't dividing by zero with doubles throw an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

This is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double varrr = Divide(10, 0);
    }

    static double Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        double c = 0;
        try
        {
            c = a / b;
            return c;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Division by zero not allowed");
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

I was expecting division by zero to throw a `DivideByZeroException` but it did not, and when I print the result on the console the output is "Infinity". Why is that?

Comment: That's for integers.

Comment: Added [tag:c#]. Maybe Jon Skeet will come.

Comment: "_The result of division by zero is, mathematically speaking, undefined, which can be expressed with a float/double (as NaN - not a number), it isn't, however, wrong in any fundamental sense.

As an integer must hold a specific numerical value, an error must be thrown on division by zero when dealing with them._"  I saw this explanation though in context of Java, but i believe same is applicable for c# as well

Comment: "Why" questions are hard to answer. Are you asking "what line of the spec defines this behaviour?", or "who wrote that line of the spec?" or "what is the history of the IEEE floating point format?" or "what design considerations make double arithmetic and integer arithmetic different?" or what? Answering any one of those questions would give a reasonable stab at answering "why" the world is the way it is, and they're all different.  **Ask a more precise question**.

Answer (score 10):

**The reason** is simple: `DivideByZeroException` is not designed for floating point numbers.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to divide an **integral or Decimal** value by zero.

So it's not for floating point values, though. According to [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Exception_handling), floating point number exceptions include:

> - Division by zero (an operation on finite operands gives an exact infinite result, e.g., 1/0 or log(0)) (**returns ±infinity by default**)

You want this code if you really want to see the exception:

```
static double Divide(int a, int b)
{
    int c = 0;
    try
    {
        c = a / b;
        return c;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Division by zero not allowed");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: apart from it'll return 1 if you do 3/2

Answer (score 5):

MSDN explains that [`DivideByZeroException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is only thrown "[when] trying to divide an **integer** or **decimal** number by zero", whereas

> floating-point operations return PositiveInfinity or NegativeInfinity
>   to signal an overflow condition.

Use [`Double.IsInfinity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
if (double.IsInfinity(c))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Division by zero not allowed");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dividing a floating-point value by zero doesn't throw an exception; it results in positive infinity, negative infinity, or not a number (NaN), according to the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic. Because the following example uses floating-point division rather than integer division, the operation does not throw a DivideByZeroException exception.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for adding the `IEEE 754 arithmetic`! Man this is so stoopid, so now instead of having an exception thrown I need to double check everytime I divide by Zero?!
Man that's stooped to the max