# Trying to make calculator with exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, calculator

So I want after clicking the result button, show the result, but typing a new number deletes the result. Like the calculator does normally.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tlacitko0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        vys.Text += b.Content.ToString();
    }

    private void tlacitkovysledek_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            vysledek();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            vys.Text = "Chyba!";
        }
    }

    private void vysledek()
    {
        string operace;
        int nic = 0;

        if (vys.Text.Contains("+"))
        {
            nic = vys.Text.IndexOf("+");
        }
        else if (vys.Text.Contains("-"))
        {
            nic = vys.Text.IndexOf("-");
        }
        else if (vys.Text.Contains("*"))
        {
            nic = vys.Text.IndexOf("*");
        }
        else if (vys.Text.Contains("/"))
        {
            nic = vys.Text.IndexOf("/");
        }
        else
        {
            
        }

        operace = vys.Text.Substring(nic, 1);
        double cislo1 = Convert.ToDouble(vys.Text.Substring(0, nic));
        double cislo2 = Convert.ToDouble(vys.Text.Substring(nic + 1, vys.Text.Length - nic - 1));

        if (operace == "+")
        {
            vys.Text += "=" + (cislo1 + cislo2);
        }
        else if (operace == "-")
        {
            vys.Text += "=" + (cislo1 - cislo2);
        }
        else if (operace == "*")
        {
            vys.Text += "=" + (cislo1 * cislo2);
        }
        else
        {
            vys.Text += "=" + (cislo1 / cislo2);
        }   
}
    private void tlacitkoC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vys.Text = "";
    }

    private void tlacitkozpet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (vys.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            vys.Text = vys.Text.Substring(0, vys.Text.Length - 1);
        }
    }
}    `
```

I will try to translate my Czech coding to you in english

```
[ 
  vys.Text = TextBox.Text ;  
  tlacitko(x) = button(x) ; 
  vysledek = result ; 
  nic = nothing ; 
  operace = operation ; 
  cislo(x) = number(x) ; 
  chyba = error ; 
]
```

Hope it helps a little..

Also, want to make exception when dividing by zero, I'm pretty new to c# and wpf even though I'm coding in it for like half a year in school, so if you could go easy on me please.

I'm so lost where to make the exception for dividing.. But I think when clicking new number after result I could try to make vys.text = ""; also don't know where to put it..

Thank you very much for your time.

THANK YOU!

Comment: You might find this helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929855/why-doesnt-dividing-by-zero-with-doubles-throw-an-exception

Answer (score 0):

You could use the text box change event and delete the text in the text box.
The code would look like this:

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        var box = (TextBox)sender;
        if (box.Text.StartsWith(result) && textBox.Text != result) {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Remove(0, result.Length);
            textBox.SelectionStart = 1;
        }
    }
```

**Edit**:
The `TextBox_TextChanged` function is used in you xaml-File, somethink like this:

```
        <TextBox x:Name="vys" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Is checks if the value in you textBox is the result of your calculation. In order that the old result will be deleted while the user is typing a new number.

The `result` value is the result string of you calculation and should be a Global variable that contains the produkt of the calculation.

---

For the division by 0 you could change you else statement

```
else
{
    vys.Text += "=" + (cislo1 / cislo2);
}
```

to something like this:

```
else
    {
        if(cislo2 != 0){
          vys.Text += "=" + (cislo1 / cislo2);
        } else {
          //Print an error or thow an exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
            var box = (TextBox)sender;
            if (box.Text.StartsWith(result) && textBox.Text != result) {
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Remove(0, result.Length);
                textBox.SelectionStart = 1;
            }
        }
Dont know what to do with this?